# Repeater: How to add binded data to control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've an ASP.NET Repeater, where a *DataView* with values *name* and *value* is binded.

Displaying my datasource in the below works fine:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_OnItemDataBound" ID="MyRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("name") %><br/>
        <%# Eval("value") %><br/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Instead I would like to add the values to a Label and a TextBox:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater_OnItemDataBound" ID="MyRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <asp:Label ID="Name" Text="<%# Eval("name") %>" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Id" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Value" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("value") %>" Visible="False" />
            <asp:TextBox ID="Id" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

But this does not seems to work. I'm getting a *The server tag is not well formed* error.

How can I use the binded values in my label and textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have implemented the quotes " wrongly.

See below.

```
     <asp:Label ID="Name" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Id" />
<asp:TextBox ID="Value" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("value") %>' Visible="False" />
```